# C# Linq How to select the distinct row count of multiple columns in a datatable

Tags: c#, linq, distinct

I have a datatable with multiple key columns (key1, key2, ..., keyN). I want to count the distinct key combinations in the table, that match a certain criteria (IsInError = false).

Basically i want to perform the query

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT key1, key2, ..., keyN FROM TABLE WHERE IsInError = 'false') A

on the datatable.

I have researched a little and found that for a table containing only one key (and with no 'where') I can do this

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();

int nRows = table
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(r => r.Field<string>("key1"))
    .Distinct()
    .Count();
```

But how would I go about doing it with multiple keys and a condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
table.AsEnumerable().Where(v => v.Field<bool>("IsInError") == false).Select(_ => new { key1 = _.key1, key2 = _.key2, ...., keyn=_.keyn }).Distinct().Count();
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly! I had to modifiy your solution slightly as I am not working with a strongly typed datatable, and IsInError is a bit field. Apart from that it was perfect!

Comment: Edited it to suit your answer better.

Comment: Thumbs up! :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A group by might be more suited to this scenario.

It will group the columns into distinct rows and return a count if desired.

i.e.

```
var groups = table.GroupBy(_ => new {_.Key1, _.Key2, _.KeyN})
                  .Select(_ => new { key = _.Key, count = _.Count());
```

This is untested code, but should help point you in the correct direction.

Comment: Thank you! I will give it a try!